# How to get all the referenced keys of one row

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table `Clan` with a tag and a creation date, and a table `ClanMember` with a reference to the `Clan.tag` (`ClanMember.clanTag`) and `Clan.created` (`ClanMember.clanCreated`).

I want to get all the members of the most recently created clan. Everything I tried thus far has resulted in the query returning all the clan members of all clans

[The 2 tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8cYds.png):

[image]

```
    CREATE TABLE Clan ([tag] varchar(255) NOT NULL, created datetime, PRIMARY KEY ([tag], created));
CREATE TABLE ClanMember ([tag] varchar(255) NOT NULL, clanCreated datetime NOT NULL, clanTag varchar(255) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY ([tag], clanCreated));
ALTER TABLE ClanMember ADD CONSTRAINT FKClanMember466676 FOREIGN KEY (clanTag, clanCreated) REFERENCES Clan ([tag], created);

INSERT INTO Clan (tag, created) VALUES ('#001','2019-10-17 12:00:00.000')
INSERT INTO Clan (tag, created) VALUES ('#001','2019-10-17 17:00:00.000')

INSERT INTO ClanMember (tag, clanCreated, clanTag) VALUES ('#cm01','2019-10-17 12:00:00.000','#001')
INSERT INTO ClanMember (tag, clanCreated, clanTag) VALUES ('#cm02','2019-10-17 12:00:00.000','#001')
INSERT INTO ClanMember (tag, clanCreated, clanTag) VALUES ('#cm03','2019-10-17 12:00:00.000','#001')

INSERT INTO ClanMember (tag, clanCreated, clanTag) VALUES ('#cm01','2019-10-17 17:00:00.000','#001')
INSERT INTO ClanMember (tag, clanCreated, clanTag) VALUES ('#cm02','2019-10-17 17:00:00.000','#001')
INSERT INTO ClanMember (tag, clanCreated, clanTag) VALUES ('#cm03','2019-10-17 17:00:00.000','#001')
```

The desired result would be that the newest clan with the tag: '#001' and all its members would be returned

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and the query you have tried.

Comment: Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it, your current attempt and your desired results. For more details, [read this.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
select cm.*
from clanmember cm
where cm.clantag = (select top (1) c.tag
                    from clans c
                    order by c.created desc
                   );
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ed97155035c6722bddd34e59d996758e) is a db<>fiddle based on your data.

Comment: This still returns all the clanmembers from all the clans

Comment: @Jorn . . . That is only possible if (1) you have one clan; (2) all clans have the same members.  The subquery returns exactly one clan tag.  The query *cannot* match multiple clan tags.  Even if all have the same `created` value, only one will be returned.

Comment: A clantag can appear multiple times, only the combination of (clanTag + created) is unique. created is always the most recent datetime and clanTag is variable. Is this possible?

Comment: @Jorn . . . Your sample data is specious.  All clan members have the same clan tag.

Comment: Yes, because that's what binds them to a clan. They are still the same clan members and also still the same clan all the other column values could differ. I could add more clanmembers with different clantags, but that would just complicate things.
Your fiddle is close to the answer I need. I just need the created to all be the same datetime and that datetime also being the most recent one.